# Как прочитать json - файл в javascript

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть JSON - файл (cities-list.json), который содержит массив из ~5000 названий городов. Как мне в файле cities.js объявить переменную, которая будет содержать массив из json файла,чтобы дальше с ним работать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

С `ajax`, например так

```
$.getJSON('cities-list.json', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: А как сделать без ajax?

Comment: импортировать json а потом распарсить его

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, подскажите пожалуйста, а как этот файл собственно импортировать в мой рабочий js файл?

Comment: массив var json = ["аав","авап"...];